# Paragraph break in poetry

Tags: poetry

I am translating an essay on translation of poetry. In this bit: Allegria di naufragi (Joy of Shipwrecks, 1919), established what remains for many people the quintessential Ungaretti poem: short lines, often only a single word; frequent paragraph breaks...

I am not sure whether a paragraph break is the same as a line break. Is it a space between lines?

Answer (score 1):

A "paragraph" of poetry would probably be referring to a stanza or a group of lines of poetry that are grouped together with extra space between them.

Example from wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanza#Example_I